# Python Bot for replying hi on Whatsapp

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, chatbot, whatsapp

What code should I add such that when someone writes "hi" to me my bot replies "hi" back?

This is the code the rest works fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver    
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_browser = 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/gladwin/Desktop/drivers/chromedriver')
chrome_browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-data-directory=')

time.sleep(15)
user_name = 'WhatsApp Bot'


user = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title="{}"]'.format(user_name))`
user.click()

message_box = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_3uMse"]')`
message_box.send_keys('Hey, I am your whatsapp bot')

message_box = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_1U1xa"]')
message_box.click()
```